# OpenCV, Linux ubuntu12.04 undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii

Tags: linux, qt, opencv, import, undefined-symbol

Now I'm struggling with OpenCV

I'm starting using NAO and got some program from other guy.

At first time, The problem was OpenCV

```
enter code here
gibeom@gibeom-SG31:~/NAO/nao_murata$ ./touching_object.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./touching_object.py", line 5, in <module>
from all_module import *
File "/home/gibeom/NAO/nao_murata/all_module.py", line 22, in <module>
import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

I got this message so I install OpenCV

as shown in this homepage

I succed install openCV

I tried again

But I got this message

```
enter code here
gibeom@gibeom-SG31:~/NAO/nao_murata$ ./trainer_nao_module.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./trainer_nao_module.py", line 7, in <module>
from all_module import *
File "/home/gibeom/NAO/nao_murata/all_module.py", line 22, in <module>
import cv
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtTest.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData11detach_growEPii
```

I didn't install qt but maybe his tutorial there is qt

Anyway after then,

I searched internet but I can't get right answer.

someone said,
"I got install a 3rd party package with libqtGui.so.4.6.2 in /usr/lib.
Just remove it then everything is fine"

I tried to do but in my /usr/lib , that file doesn't exist.

I want to show my usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ folder, because of size limitation I can't

And I have reputation point less than 10 I can't upload image.

Anyway, trainier_nao_module.py

```
enter code here
1 #! /usr/bin/env python
2 # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
3 
4 # this program is for trainer-nao
5 
6 #--- import all original modules ---#
**7 from all_module import ***
8 #-------------------------#
9 
10 #--- import user defined modules ---#
```

,   all_module.py

```
enter code here

1 #! /usr/bin/env python
2 # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
3 
4 # this file imports original modules
5 
6 import config
7 import config_trainer
8 
9 import os
10 import sys
11 import time
12 import string
13 import pygame
14 
15 from naoqi import ALProxy
16 
17 from pygame.locals import *
18 
19 from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Array, Value, Event
20 
21 from math import *
**22 import cv**
23 from vision_definitions import *
```

python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py

```
enter code here

from cv2.cv import *
```

If you need more information to solve this problem,

please reply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you gt a message like this, invoke “c++filt” with the undefined symbol. It will tell you the plain C++ name of the symbol. Usually, that is much easier to understand:

> c++filt _ZN9QlistData11detach_growEPii

#### Maybe, if you reinstall QT Library could solve this problem.

http://qt-project.org/downloads